# How to handle javascript on page with thousands of checkboxes in IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, performance

I am having problems with code written in ASP.NET with some javascript, doing a postback to the server for changes made to a grid of approximately 8,000 checkboxes. The this is, while I was testing it, everything seemed ok with approximately 1,000 checkboxes with IE6. But now, having imported the real data, I am stuck with the slowness of IE6 and the reality that the code I wrote is not going to cut it.

I have to use IE6 to test it because unfortunately, the client demands the web app to be fully functional with it. How can I boost speed of the page?

**EDIT**

I counted the rows and colums: 66 * 110 = 7260 checkboxes on the page.

**CODE**

[...]

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repChkAssociations" runat="server" DataSource="<%#Failures%>">
<ItemTemplate>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbEqClassFailure" runat="server" Enabled="<%#AllowEditAssociations%>"
            ToolTip='ommited code'
            Checked='ommited code'
            OnClick="setIsDirty(true);"
            >
        </asp:CheckBox>
    </td>
</ItemTemplate>
```

[...]

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var isDirty;
    var identifiter;

    function SaveAssociation() {
        setIsDirty(false);
    }

    // check if the page has been modified
    function CheckIsDirty(_id) {
        setID(_id);
        if (getIsDirty() == true) {
            ShowConfirmPopup();
        } else {
            ShowGridPopup(); 
        }
    }

    function ShowGridPopup() {
        if (getID() == "EqClasses") {
            ShowClassPopup();
        } else if (getID() == "Failures") {
            ShowFailurePopup();
        }
    }

    // isDirty setter        
    function setIsDirty(changeVal) {
        isDirty = changeVal;
    }

    // isDirty getter
    function getIsDirty() {
        return isDirty;
    }

function ClickSaveButton() {
    var _id = $('a[id$="butSaveAssociation"]').attr("ID");
    __doPostBack(_id.replace("_", "$"), '');
}

function ShowClassPopup() {
    var _id = '<%= eqClassPopup.BehaviorID %>';
    var modal = $find(_id);
    modal.show();
}

function ShowFailurePopup() {
    var _id = '<%= failurePopup.BehaviorID %>';
    var modal = $find(_id);
    modal.show();
}

function ShowConfirmPopup() {
    var _id = '<%= confirmPopup.BehaviorID %>';
    var modal = $find(_id);
    modal.show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You don't want to boost the speed, you want to decrease the slowness. Let's see the javascript. Do you have a demo page? If there is no code to look at, you will only get vague guesses and "best practice" lectures.

Comment: *"How can I boost speed of the page?"* - Redesign it. I cannot think of a good reason for ever having 8,000 checkboxes on a single HTML page. Or any interface, anywhere.

Comment: It's in my nature not to question your app without seeing it, but Rob's got a point. 7260 checkboxes on the page is ridiculous. Hundreds... sure. Nearly ten thousand? Reeks of poor design.

Comment: Personally, I have a hard time believing ie6 can display even one checkbox without having memory issues.

Comment: @Everyone, I know this is terrible design, but the customer asked specifically for this, so we have to deliver, and if he wants us to change it during the next sprint, we will do it! But in the mean time... I am guessing it is caused by the use of jQuery's `.find()` method in my code.

Comment: @JFB: It would be helpful if we *could* see the code.

Comment: @JFB - If he wants 8000 checkboxes on a page, it's up to you to convince him that his design is ridiculous and suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: @JFB: This code doesn't help at all. What does this even do? I was looking forward to helping you but... I don't even see any use of `.find()` or *any* jQuery for that matter. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Wesley, sorry about my hesitation about revealing code to stack, it's because I've signed a contract of non-divulge...

Comment: I understand that if this is how the customer wants it, it may be difficult to sway them from the idea.  But, as the developer, and the knowledge expert in web design, it is also your job to tell them what is and is not possible.  Tell them that if they want to use a browser from a decade ago (literally), there will be some things that are just not possible.  When you are educating them about this, *also* suggest an alternative.  Say, "we can't do X,  but we *can* do Y, and this is why"

Comment: @Everyone, wow. -2 and excuses for the client. thanks alot.

Comment: The client isn't always right. "The client wants this" is not a valid excuse to put EIGHT THOUSAND checkboxes on a page while using IE6, of all things. I'm not sure what kind of answer you hoped to get.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is the page slow even with all the JS removed? I suspect that it is.

Comment: For all of the naysayers here, I just created a Google Spreadsheet with 8000 numeric cells in it and saved it. It worked, without even breathing hard. So 1) you can't tell me its impossible, and 2) you can't tell me that there are no feasible use cases.

Comment: @Robert just curious - IE6? Not that your argument is not valid, I'm just genuinely curious if IE6 could pull that off.

Comment: @Matt: I have IE8. Compatibility mode is locked out when I'm in Google Docs (DOCTYPE is HTML), so I guess Google assumes you're using a modern browser. Personally, I'd rather get flogged than to have to develop in IE6.

Comment: Well then, Robert, your test doesn't really apply, since this question is specifically about IE6. And I have a hard time beliving that there is any use case where 8000 check boxes is the necessary, or even optimal, solution.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - Point noted that rendering the markup efficiently may be *possible*. However, I must defend my naysayer stance: I can't think of an 8000-cell spreadsheet I'd ever want to use, either. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Granted, I don't know what you're doing, but having 8,000 check boxes on one page seems pretty user-unfriendly to me.  Consider adding pagination & filtering to keep the number of check boxes per page under, perhaps, 100?

**EDIT** - You also seem to think this is an IE6 problem.  I'd hazard a guess that *any* browser would have troubles with the volume you're talking.

**DOUBLE EDIT** - Okay, after looking over your code, I'm certain the only way to improve speed is to reduce the number of controls on the website.  You're not doing anything crazy in the JS.

Comment: Firefox is alot faster in fact, and I haven't tried chrome, but I bet that it is even faster...

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added another edit with the jQuery code... ANd there is no `.find()`, I've mistaken with `$find()`

Answer (score 2):

Echoing @Matt Grande - you're trying to do something impossible. IE6 runs javascript really, really slowly. It's also going to be proportionally slower on the likely ancient hardware your end-user may be working on. It's damn near impossible to avoid memory leaks no matter what you do. This just isn't a good approach.

If you really need 6,000 checkboxes on a page, then consider an alternative approach. For example, use a single image with all the checkboxes pre-rendered. Capture mouse click events, figure out which box they checked using the mouse position, render a checkmark with VML, and save the information as an array or JSON in a hidden field.