# Internet Explorer very slow using lots of checkboxes with valueChangeListener/ajax

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsf, ajax4jsf

I have a jsf site with a html table, which shows up to 300 rows and 50 columns. Except the table-header and the first column (someones name) all the cells contain a checkbox.

So i have a form with up to 15.000 checkboxes.

Here's the code:

```
<h:form>
<table>
   <a4j:repeat var="item" value="#{listBean.listItems}" rows="0" >
      <tr>
         <td>#{item.name}</td>

         <a4j:repeat var="box" value="#{item.activations}" >

            <td>
            <a4j:region renderRegionOnly="true" >
               <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{box.checked}"
                     valueChangeListener="#{listBean.activationChanged}"
                     immediate="true" >
                  <a4j:support event="onchange" />
               </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </a4j:region>
            </td>

         </a4j:repeat>

      </tr>
   </a4j:repeat>
</table>
</h:form>
```

As you can see, i already use regions to keep the rendering fast. I need to use the valueChangelistener, because we must not use a button for submitting.
The customer also wants to avoid paging here.

Firefox is very fast. But in IE the checking of a single box takes 3-5 seconds.

Can anybody help me increase the performance of IE here?

thx!

regards

Comment: Yes, use pagination!  Server side or client side, doesn't matter, you should never load 300 rows all at once, especially if one row has 50 columns.

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231059/how-to-handle-javascript-on-page-with-thousands-of-checkboxes-in-ie6/6231395#6231395 -- nothing good will come of having a page with that many checkboxes. Redesign.

Comment: Good luck. IE with large tables, plus JavaScript = slow. Bad design = bad performance

Comment: thanks for your comment. i also think that this will be a very confusing and overloaded page for a webapp. but it's requested not to use pagination as this case shows up seldomly.

Comment: Just because you can't use pagination doesn't mean you have to use 15,000 checkboxes with an event bound to each one. *Redesign*. I don't know what's making it slow, if it's the event or the checkbox. Try replacing the checkbox with a span contianing an "X" or an "O" and bind an event to that instead, e.g.

Comment: ok, i guess we all know this is not user friendly. I will force pagination.
Thank you jamietre for this analysis option. i think i'll try this soon.